# `the node was low on resource imagefs` -- Causing pod eviction on a regular basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-x

I am using Jenkins-X for a relatively large project, which consists of approximately 30 modules, 15 of which are services (and therefore, contain Dockerfiles, and a respective Helm chart for deployment).

During some of these relatively large builds, I am intermittently (~every other build) seeing a build pod become evicted, using `kubectl describe pod <podname>` I can investigate and I've noticed that the pod is evicted due to the following:

`the node was low on resource imagefs`

Full data:

```
Name:         maven-96wmn
Namespace:    jx
Node:         ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal/
Start Time:   Tue, 06 Nov 2018 10:22:54 +0000
Labels:       jenkins=slave
              jenkins/jenkins-maven=true
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Failed
Reason:       Evicted
Message:      The node was low on resource: imagefs.
IP:           
Containers:
  maven:
    Image:      jenkinsxio/builder-maven:0.0.516
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
    Args:
      cat
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     400m
      memory:  512Mi
    Environment:
      JENKINS_SECRET:       131c407141521c0842f62a69004df926be6cb531f9318edf0885aeb96b0662b4
      JENKINS_TUNNEL:       jenkins-agent:50000
      DOCKER_CONFIG:        /home/jenkins/.docker/
      GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL:     jenkins-x@googlegroups.com
      GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL:  jenkins-x@googlegroups.com
      GIT_COMMITTER_NAME:   jenkins-x-bot
      _JAVA_OPTIONS:        -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Xms10m -Xmx192m
      GIT_AUTHOR_NAME:      jenkins-x-bot
      JENKINS_NAME:         maven-96wmn
      XDG_CONFIG_HOME:      /home/jenkins
      JENKINS_URL:          http://jenkins:8080
      HOME:                 /home/jenkins
    Mounts:
      /home/jenkins from workspace-volume (rw)
      /home/jenkins/.docker from volume-2 (rw)
      /home/jenkins/.gnupg from volume-3 (rw)
      /root/.m2 from volume-1 (rw)
      /var/run/docker.sock from volume-0 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from jenkins-token-smvvp (ro)
  jnlp:
    Image:      jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:3.14-1
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      131c407141521c0842f62a69004df926be6cb531f9318edf0885aeb96b0662b4
      maven-96wmn
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  128Mi
    Environment:
      JENKINS_SECRET:       131c407141521c0842f62a69004df926be6cb531f9318edf0885aeb96b0662b4
      JENKINS_TUNNEL:       jenkins-agent:50000
      DOCKER_CONFIG:        /home/jenkins/.docker/
      GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL:     jenkins-x@googlegroups.com
      GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL:  jenkins-x@googlegroups.com
      GIT_COMMITTER_NAME:   jenkins-x-bot
      _JAVA_OPTIONS:        -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Xms10m -Xmx192m
      GIT_AUTHOR_NAME:      jenkins-x-bot
      JENKINS_NAME:         maven-96wmn
      XDG_CONFIG_HOME:      /home/jenkins
      JENKINS_URL:          http://jenkins:8080
      HOME:                 /home/jenkins
    Mounts:
      /home/jenkins from workspace-volume (rw)
      /home/jenkins/.docker from volume-2 (rw)
      /home/jenkins/.gnupg from volume-3 (rw)
      /root/.m2 from volume-1 (rw)
      /var/run/docker.sock from volume-0 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from jenkins-token-smvvp (ro)
Volumes:
  volume-0:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/run/docker.sock
    HostPathType:  
  volume-2:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  jenkins-docker-cfg
    Optional:    false
  volume-1:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  jenkins-maven-settings
    Optional:    false
  workspace-volume:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  
  volume-3:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  jenkins-release-gpg
    Optional:    false
  jenkins-token-smvvp:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  jenkins-token-smvvp
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age   From                                                   Message
  ----     ------                 ----  ----                                                   -------
  Normal   Created                7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Created container
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "workspace-volume"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "volume-0"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "volume-1"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "volume-2"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "volume-3"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "jenkins-token-smvvp"
  Normal   Pulled                 7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Container image "jenkinsxio/builder-maven:0.0.516" already present on machine
  Normal   Scheduled              7m    default-scheduler                                      Successfully assigned maven-96wmn to ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Started                7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Started container
  Normal   Pulled                 7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Container image "jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:3.14-1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Created container
  Normal   Started                7m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Started container
  Warning  Evicted                5m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  The node was low on resource: imagefs.
  Normal   Killing                5m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Killing container with id docker://jnlp:Need to kill Pod
  Normal   Killing                5m    kubelet, ip-192-168-66-176.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Killing container with id docker://maven:Need to kill Pod
```

How can I remedy this issue? I generally do not fully understand what imagefs is, how I configure / increase it, or avoid saturating it.

ps. sorry this post is written so passively, I had to use an active tone to make the wording wordy enough for SO to allow me to not just post a code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved; due to underlying size of storage being only 20gb, changed to 50gb in EBS and rebooted the nodes (which had increased nodefs) which removed this problem (as imagefs no longer was saturated).